# Need assistance in running my mapreduce program from eclipse maven project

Tags: mapreduce, maven-2

I have created a maven project in eclipse wherein i have added the dependency of apache hadoop.Now i have written a simple word count mapreduce program, Can i simply run this program as 'Java application'?Online articles advise that mapreduce programs are run after creating the jars.Is that mandatory even if i am using a maven project?
If yes - kindly assist me on how to make jar of my mapreduce programs.

Comment: Please take the online tutorial and you will get to know how you can run map reduce. Basically yes you will need jar file which will get pushed onto each map.reduce node before running the phase, you will need all your daemons to be up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can run the driver class as a Java Application.  I'm assuming that your main method eventually configures and submits the job.  Keep in mind that if your application uses HDFS (e.g. your reducer outputs to a distributed sequential file in HDFS) then you need to install HDFS (and all of its prereqs) on your system in order for your app to run.